# Are conda dependencies platform independent?

Tags: python, testing, travis-ci, conda

A recent [Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/geopandas/geopandas/jobs/538372214) of the open source [geopandas project](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) makes use of a [YAML file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geopandas/geopandas/master/ci/travis/35-minimal.yaml) to set up the remote environment on the build machine. It seems that the build is done on a non-Windows machine (unsure if it is Linux or Ubuntu), but it seems to set up the environment with no issues.

I tried to set up an identical environment with the purposes of running the test suite locally. I executed the following command in my anaconda prompt:

```
conda env create --file D:\github_projects\geopandas\ci\travis\35-minimal.yaml --name geopandas-dev-python3
```

Unfortunately this raises an error:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - fiona=1.7
  - numpy=1.12
  - python=3.5
  - shapely=1.5
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

This is a bit confusing to me since I was under the impression that python dependencies as implemented by Anaconda are platform-independent. Is this assumption wrong? If not then why am I getting this error on my local Windows machine, while the remote non-Windows machine seems to be setting up the environment with no issues?

Comment: Yes, I have just realize they have an AppVeyor project with python2 and python3 builds... Unfortunately I cannot extract artifacts and can only see a main log... Is there a way to extract artifacts for each test? I'm ready to accept your answer if you wish to post it...